# How to authorize user with taken token from IdentityServer?

Tags: .net-core, identityserver4, authorize

I have created an IdentityServer project ( B ) with this configuration :

```
new Client
{
    ClientId = "ro.client",
    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
    ClientSecrets =
    {
        new Secret("secret".Sha256())
    },
    AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
}
```

And I have project B with it's custom login page, When the user enter his/her user & password, I send this info to project B's backend, and through this code I can get the token from identity server - project A:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
        var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync(_configuration["App:Authority"]);
        if (disco.IsError)
        {
            throw new System.Exception("get info from identity server is failed.");
        }

        var tokenResponse = await client.RequestPasswordTokenAsync(new PasswordTokenRequest
        {
            Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,
            ClientId = "ro.client",
            ClientSecret = "secret",

            UserName = "bob",
            Password = "Pass123$",
            Scope = "api1"
        });

        var accessToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;
```

Now what I want to achieve is that somehow I make this user authorized and save the token in cookie, So when this user call another action with authorize attribute, does not redirect him/her to login page.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: There may be more suitable grant types that you can use, take a look here: http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html Also take a look at the samples: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples

Comment: Based on description of identityServer, is it ok to develope another login page other than identity server ?

Comment: It always depends. Just be aware of the difference: in other flows the credentials remain unknown to the client app, while with RO the client app has to use the credentials. This means that the responsibility shifts. Where IdentityServer requires a secured line, the client app may not be that safe.

Comment: Please also read this: https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications

Comment: Are the actions requiring the authorize attribute going to be hosted within project A, project B, or another application entirely? Also, do you plan to use the cookie as the main authentication scheme for the authorize attribute or the bearer token? If you plan to use the bearer token then you’ll need some extra code during the configuration of the options in “AddJwtBearer”